# How do I search substrings in a database using Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As we know 
     Things.where("topic = ?","blah") 
searches for topics that match "blah"

However, what if I want to search for topics that contain "bla"

How should I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a [post](http://codingclues.eu/2009/using-sql-like-with-find-in-ruby-on-rails/) that describes it.

Basically, you use [SQL `LIKE` expression](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-LIKE.asp) to match strings that *contain* something.  Using `where("topic like ?", "%bla%")` would do the trick.

However, naive solution is prone to attacks due to lack of sanitizing.  If user types its own `%` wildcard character, he can get data you don't mean to provide!  The post above suggests that you manually sanitize such user inputs:

```
escaped_str =  "bla".gsub ('%', '\%').gsub ('_', '\_')
Topic.where("topic like ?", "%" + escaped_str + "%")
```